# WPF tracing events issue

Tags: c#, wpf, trace, listeners

I have some problem filter tracing events. Here's my code:

```
PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
Stream myFile = File.Create("trace.txt");
listener = new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Listeners.Add(listener);
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning;
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, "Test my warning");
```

Then i run my app and expect that file trace.txt will contain "Test my warning" string, however this file is empty. But if I change one string in code to

```
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;
```

I can see string "Test my warning" in file called "trace.txt". But this is always traces all event types, not only warnings. But I want to trace only warnings. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add :

```
 PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Flush();
```

At the end and it will works, for any source level.

Actually as soon as you have another level than `SourceLevels.All`, you have to flush your [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write it in your listeners.